# Google Analytics event tracking counting all site hits?

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics, event-tracking

I have been trying to set up event tracking for our company website and have hit a bit of a stumbling block.

I am tracking clicks to our telephone number. It appears that each website visit is being counted as call and appears under the tracking tab.

All I would like to measure is how many times people are 'clicking' to call us.

Am I overseeing something?

```
ga('create', 'UA-48180919-1', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true});
ga('require', 'linker');
ga('linker:autoLink', ['www........com/'] );
ga('send', 'pageview');
ga('send', 'event', 'calls', 'click', 'tel:00000000000', 9);





<a href="tel:0000 000 0000" onClick=”ga(‘send’, ‘event’, ‘calls’, ‘click’, ‘tel:00000000000’, 9);”>0000 000 0000</a>
```

I'm currently looking on Real Time/Events

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: From the code you've posted it appears that you're sending the click event twice, you only need it `onClick`

Comment: Thanks Billy. I'm fairly new to all this. I should have mentioned that the upper coding is Syntax and the bottom coding is what I placed in the header. Do I need to replace the onClick= with onClick  ?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this is something that is not possible through Google Analytics alone. Instead, you have to use Google Adwords.